# CISD JHDF5: Reading Group/Dataset attributes table

Tags: hdf5

I am checking out [JHDF5](http://svncisd.ethz.ch/doc/hdf5/hdf5-14.12/) wrapper package for HDF5.
I can read a single attribute like the following:

```
   reader.string().read("a string");
   reader.bool().getAttr("a string", "important");
   reader.time().getAttr("a string", "timestamp");
```

However, I want to loop through my attributes table and print Names and Values of attributes of different data types. How do I do that? I do not know the data type beforehand, so I cant use `string()`, `bool()`, `int32()`, etc directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> names = reader.object().getAllAttributeNames(path);
```

Where path is in your case is "a string".
Base path is "/".